# python selenium automation on myntra

Tags: python, selenium

some people wants just to look at all clothes available on sites, so why not to automate the myntra website, my code is as follow

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
import random


from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys




seed = 1
random.seed(seed)

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.myntra.com/")

element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='desktop-header-cnt']/div[2]/div[3]/input")

# Put the word "history" in the search box and hit enter
element.send_keys("pantaloons")
element.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

time.sleep(3)
for i in range(1000):
    for i in range(120):
        actions = ActionChains(driver)
        actions.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
        actions.perform()
        time.sleep(0.10)

    element=driver.find_element_by_xpath(" //*[@id='desktopSearchResults']/div[2]/section/div[2]/ul/li[12]/a")
    element.click()
    time.sleep(1)
```

my question is can we pause the script running on mouse movement for 3 seconds? it would be enough time to look closely a item. any suggestions are accepted. Thanks in advance, if you run my code.      the page are skipped by 3, i don't know why.

Comment: the page are skipped by 3, i don't know why.

Comment: i am absolute noob in selenium, so i just get the next button by xpath and clicked it.

Comment: can you explain what does it mean by script running on mouse movement.

Comment: pause the downward movement of page when some mouse movement occurs.